# Apache Maven install “'mvn' not recognized as an internal or external command” after setting OS environmental variables?

Tags: maven, installation, environment-variables, configure

I have Windows 7. I downloaded and unzipped apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.tar.gz.

***1) M2 and M2_HOME are under "System variables"***

M2 is set to my maven bin folder(ex:C:\Program Files\Java\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin

M2_HOME is set to my maven main directory(ex:C:\Program Files\Java\apache-maven-3.3.3)

***2) PATH and MAVEN OPS are under "User Variables"***

PATH is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin; %M2%

MAVEN_OPS set to -Xms256m -Xmx512m

------Things i've tried: restarting, running command prompt as system admin.

Comment: Try quoting everything, i.e. PATH as "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin" and M2 as "C:\Program Files\Java\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin".

Answer (score 0):

Ensure JAVA_HOME environment variable is set and points to your JDK installation.

Update system variables "PATH" : add "C:\Program Files\Java\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin"